WooCommerce Prevent Order from being placed
Wordpress 6.6.2
WooCommerce 9.3.3
Based on my reading I should be able to prevent an order from being placed using the woocommerce_checkout_process hook. I've tried simplifying my plugin code to be the following just to test:
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_order_validation');
function custom_order_validation() {
    wc_add_notice(__('Order Invalid'), 'error');
}

With the plugin active and installed I am able to fully place an order. I am working in a development environment connected to the WooCommerce Test Payment Gateway so I'm not sure if that's a contributing factor or not.
Any ideas?

Based on a review of the relevant code, try throwing an error rather than using wc_add_notice() (untested):
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', static function () {
    throw new Exception( __( 'Order invalid.' ) );
} );


Thanks for the response Caleb, trying this code resulted in no difference in behavior and the order was completed.

Try moving that code to an mu-plugin, and see if it works then.
